# $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I can't figure a way to work this one out, I know it has to go to 1. this is the best I could do:

$0^0$ $\le$ $n^\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}$ $\le$ $n^\frac{1}{n}$

but I feel like that's cheating. It is causing problems because $n^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ $\ge$ $n^\frac{1}{n}$ and $n^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ $\ge$ $n^\frac{-1}{n}$. so I can't find a way to sandwich it for squeeze theorem.

I know of the Binomial expansion trick for $n^\frac{1}{n}$ but that gives two lower bounds since $n^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ≥ $n^0$ and  $n^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ≥ $n^\frac{1}{n}$ ? since n ≥ $\sqrt{n}$ => $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ≥ $\frac{1}{n}$. I can't seem to find a upper bound I know converges to 1

Comment: Notice that $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n^{1/\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/\sqrt n^{\sqrt n})^2=\lim_{m\to\infty}1/m^{1/m}$

Comment: this is very cool, but can you make substitutions with integers like that? I know it's possible for variables, I just haven't seen it done with sequences

Answer (score 0):

If $0 < a $
and
$b_n
=\dfrac1{n^{1/n^{a}}}
$

(this problem
is the case
$a = \frac12$)
then

$\ln(b_n)
=\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{a}}
\to 0
$
(as has been shown here,
often by me)
so
$b_n \to 1$.

Comment: This is a very neat approach, but unfortunately beyond where we are at. So I need some Alegra trick, without using functions.

Comment: Do you have logs? How are they defined?

Comment: no logs at all, unfortunately, the only Identity we can use is |sin/cos| $\le$ 1. But since trigonometric functions are defined in this book everything else is off-limits as well.